# Bash: Show info after grep search term

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm trying to output information about a machine's system hardware in a bash script. What I'm using is grep to get information about total memory and free memory.

```
echo -n -e "RAM:\t"
cat /proc/meminfo | grep "MemTotal"
```

My output shows "MemTotal: 3994850 MB". What I want is just the memory information itself. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one awk would be enough instead of multiple piped command here:

```
awk '/MemTotal/{print $2}' /proc/meminfo
15404808
```

If you want unit also then use:

```
awk '/MemTotal/{print $2, $3}' /proc/meminfo
15404808 kB
```